# how to update and insert records in php using mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

How to update and insert the data using php and database will be mongodb

```
'[
{
_id: 5,
unique: true,
name: "Joseph",
password: "mangalore"
},
{
_id: 9,
unique: true,
name: "John",
password: {
passcode1: 1,
passcode2: 2
}
},
{
_id: 10,
unique: true,
name: "Ashraf",
password: {
passcode1: 2,
passcode2: 3
}
},
{
_id: 11,
unique: true,
name: "Rajesh",
password: {
passcode1: 3,
passcode2: 4
}
}
]`
```

Please tel me how to update and insert the data.
i have already done for retrieving and code is

```
$id = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('login2')->where('password.passcode1','>',1)->get();
        return $id;
```

Comment: I am using laravel 5.4 so for that i write databse code in model and call it in controller and display the output. so now I want to write same code for updating,inserting and deleting the data. please any suggestion how can i do it..

Answer (score 1):

Insert:

```
$mongo  = new MongoClient();
$db     = $mongo->mydb1;

/* Note: In mongodb if the specified collection is not present than it will automatically create it and the document is inserted in the newly created collection */

$data   = array('emp_id' => '1', 'first_name' => 'Tiger' , 'last_name' => 'Nixon', 'position' => 'System Architect', 'email'  => 't.nixon@datatables.net', 'office' => 'Edinburgh', 'start_date' => '2011-04-25 00:00:00', 'age' => '61', 'salary' => '320800', 'projects' => array('Project1', 'Project2', 'Project3'));

$collection = $db->createCollection("emp_details");

if($collection->insert($data))
{
    echo '<p style="color:green;">Record inserted successfully</p>';
}
else
{
    echo '<p style="color:red;">Error in insertion</p>';
}
```

Update:

```
$mongo  = new MongoClient();
$db     = $mongo->mydb1;

/*  Note: Here we are using the update() method. The update() method update values in the existing document  */

$collection = $db->createCollection("emp_details");

$newdata = array('$set' => array("age" => "55", "salary" => "320000"));
// specify the column name whose value is to be updated. If no such column than a new column is created with the same name.

$condition = array("emp_id" => "1");
// specify the condition with column name. If no such column exist than no record will update

if($collection->update($condition, $newdata))
{
    echo '<p style="color:green;">Record updated successfully</p>';
}
else
{
    echo '<p style="color:red;">Error in update</p>';
}
```

Comment: I have to write a code in model. so for that any suggestion?

Comment: I am using laravel so for that I write databse code in model then call it controller

Comment: Get the basic idea of model in that framework and try it yourself

Comment: I have done it for retrieval but  now I want to know how can i write the code for update, insert and delete